# SELECT count(*) with ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to ask you, if its correct if i use this ORDER BY in a SELECT COUNT(*)

```
Orginal: SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM players WHERE totalpoints>?    

Modified: SELECT count(*) AS cnt FROM players WHERE totalpoints>? ORDER BY timeontheserver DESC
```

In the Orginal query it outputs the players given "rank" in the database.

But i just noticed that some "players" are having the same amount of points and they get kinda reversed. So it should kinda give the player with an higher amount of "timeontheserver" the better "rank".
I hope you could understand this, thank you.

Comment: Timontheserver isn't in your SELECT clause, so the two queries will have an identical output; namely, the count of records from `players` where `totalpoints` is greater than `?`

Comment: your count(*) will return only one value... what's to sort?... Now if you were returning player name having points >? with count then ordering makes sense.

Comment: SQL applies the `Order by` operation at the end after all the aggregations are done. So I dont think that would have any impact on the order of your evaluation, but resultset display order could ofcourse be modified using `order by`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COUNT(*) will give you a number, you'll want to do a group by on the field you're ordering by to get what you want.

```
SELECT timeontheserver ,count(*) AS cnt FROM players 
WHERE totalpoints>? GROUP BY timeontheserver  ORDER BY timeontheserver DESC
```